# Wordpress pagination static page

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I'm working on a Wordpress template and want to use a static page as homepage. I made a pagination on that page, but when I go to another, the URL changes and also the posts of the other page shows up, but the pagination's current page is the same. It says that it's still on 'Page 1 of ....' in the pagination.

Does someone know how I can change the current page?

```js
function custom_pagination($numpages = '', $pagerange = '', $paged='') {

  if (empty($pagerange)) {
    $pagerange = 2;
  }
  global $paged;
  if (empty($paged)) {
    $paged = 1;
  }
  if ($numpages == '') {
    global $wp_query;
    $numpages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
    if(!$numpages) {
        $numpages = 1;
    }
  }
  $pagination_args = array(
    'base'            => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',
    'format'          => 'page/%#%',
    'total'           => $numpages,
    'current'         => $page,
    'show_all'        => False,
    'end_size'        => 1,
    'mid_size'        => $pagerange,
    'prev_next'       => True,
    'prev_text'       => __('&laquo;'),
    'next_text'       => __('&raquo;'),
    'type'            => 'plain',
    'add_args'        => false,
    'add_fragment'    => ''
  );

  $paginate_links = paginate_links($pagination_args);

  if ($paginate_links) {
      echo "<span class='page-numbers page-num'>Page " . $page . " of " . $numpages . "</span> ";
      echo $paginate_links;
  }

}
```

```html
<?php 

  $paged = ( get_query_var('page') ) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;

  $query_args = array(
      'post_type' => 'post',
      'posts_per_page' => 12,
      'paged' => $paged,
      'page' => $paged
    );

  $the_query = new WP_Query( $query_args ); ?>

  <?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

    <!-- the loop -->
    <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();

// Get all posts
                        get_template_part( 'content', 'post' );

endwhile; ?></div>
    <!-- end of the loop -->

   <nav class='paging-navigation'>
  <?php
      if (function_exists(custom_pagination)) {
        custom_pagination($the_query->max_num_pages,"",$paged);
      }
    ?></nav>


  <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

  <?php else:  ?>
    <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
  <?php endif; ?></div>
```

Comment: remove 'page' => $paged from $query_args

Comment: doesn't do anything.. :(

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem! Put this:

```
<?php
  if (function_exists(custom_pagination)) {
    custom_pagination($the_query->max_num_pages,"",$paged);
  }
```

After the wp_reset_postdata, also removed 'page' => $paged from $query_args, this worked for me. :)